# How can i plot graph whit 5 minutes time interval

Tags: python, json, datetime, graph, plot

i am having problem with ploting graph in python.
i have one `.json` file.i have to read "times" from this file.
program can read every "times" from file and i add all of this to list.
i want to plot graph with 5 minutes interval.then i have chosen times that in list which ended with 00 or 05 and i added to another list.
by the way my list2 has object like this "2015-1-03 1:15:00" 
and my list1 has integers like 20 etc.

Finally when i try plot graph with that code:

```
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(range(len(pd1)), list1)
plt.xticks(range(len(grapdict)), list2, rotation=25)
pl.show()
```

it print:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

i search from this site. i found x can't be list. i tried somethings i searched datetime etc. but error again :(

how can i do that in this way or other way? Is there any more basic way than i have?

i just want to plot a graph and i want to it's x axis start from 8:27 (example) and i must end with 8:47(example). but only 8:30 ,8:35, 8,40 , 8:45 must be seen on the graph(5 minute interval). And these times can be changeable.Because i have to read these from file.If time in file starts 3:47(example) graph must start from 3:47 and it must end with 4:03(example). But like i said only 3:50, 3:55, 4:00 must be on graph x axis.my file is really huge dictionary file.And times are kept in d[time] line by line.

Comment: Can you try to clarify exactly what you're doing here? What's in your input files? What are `pd1` and `grapdict`? Your error typically indicates that you've provided two arrays for your xy data that are different size. If you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would go a long way to helping answer your question.

Comment: sorry u are right. i just want to plot a graph and i want to it's x axis start from 8:27 (example)  and i must end with 8:47(example). but only 8:30 ,8:35, 8,40 , 8:45 must be seen on the graph(5 minute interval). And these times can be changeable.Because i have to read these from file.If time in file starts 3:47(example) graph must start from 3:47 and it must end with 4:03(example). But like i said only 3:50, 3:55, 4:00 must be on graph x axis.my file is really huge dictionary file.And times are kept in d[time] line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that your x and y values are in separate files and assuming that you're using matplotlib for your plotting, I think the best way for you to proceed is to use the Python [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) package to convert your x values to `datetime` objects. Then matplotlib can use these objects directly for the x values. If your x values look like "2015-01-03 01:15:00", you can convert them to `datetime` like this:

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.strptime( '2015-01-03 01:15:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

When you're plotting your data, you need to make sure that your x and y lists are the same length, particularly because you're pulling them from separate files. Then you can do what you want to do as in this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from numpy import sin, arange
from math import pi

starttime = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 8, 8, 37, 0)
delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

# Create label locations and strings
sample_times = [starttime + i * delta for i in range(60)]
label_locations = [d for d in sample_times if d.minute % 5 == 0]
labels = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in label_locations]

# Create some y data to plot
x = arange(60)
y = sin(x * 2 * pi / 60.0)

# Do the plotting. You'll probably want to make adjustments to accommodate the size 
# of the labels.
plt.plot(sample_times, y)
plt.xticks(label_locations, labels, rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks for your help.sorry for i wrote thanks messages very late :(